# Regex to replace tr tag with th tag anywhere in html file

Tags: c#, regex, winforms

What should be the regex for replacing a `tr` tag with a `th` tag for the `table` tag anywhere in an HTML file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Regex.Replace(html, @"(?<=<(/)?)th(?=[\s>])", "tr", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: +1.  Beat me to it.  You'll also need to replace the closing tags: Regex.Replace(strHTML, @"</th(?=[\s>])", "</tr", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Comment: @Diadistis,Will it replace all the `th` tags anywhere there is `tr` tag in the html file whether there is attributes or anything ?

Comment: new Regex("(<(?:/){0,1})(th)( |>)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.MultipleLine).Replace(html, m => m.Group[1].Value + "tr" + m.Group[3].Value);

Not tested...

Comment: @Diadistis,Sorry my mistake but I want to replace `tr` tag instead of `th` tag.

Comment: @Harikrishna: just swap them : Regex.Replace(html, @"(?<=<(/)?)tr(?=[\s>])", "th", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Comment: Could be shortened: `@"(?<=<(/)?)tr\b"`; also I don't know if whitespace might occur between `<`, `/` and `tr` - if so, `@"(?<=<\s*(/)?\s*)tr\b"` might be safer.

Comment: @Diadistis,Will it just replace `tr` OR  `<tr>` means with `<` and `>` ?

Comment: @Harikrishna: it will replace `tr` when found in `<tr` or `</tr`